# Border in matrix with defined row and column

Tags: excel

it´s my first post.

I have different tables.
for example: range(F9:M16), range(F24:M31) etc.

in A1 I define the row and in B1 I define the column. 
example: G3 = 3, H3 = 4

With this information I will create a red bold border in H12.

because in range(F9:M16) is H12 the row 3 and column 4. and in the other ranges are diferent.

so i need a makro, because I do it every time manually.

[image]

thanks for your help.

regards
thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight cells according to specific conditions, Conditional Formatting is usually the way to go; you can do a lot of very neat things automatically without resorting to a macro.

In this case:

- select the range on which you want to apply your format (F9:M16)
- create a new conditional formatting, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- as a formula, use: `=AND(COLUMN(F9)-COLUMN($F$9)=$G$3;ROW(F9)-ROW($F$9)=$H$3)`
- define your format (red border or whatever else you fancy)

Repeat for all your tables, adapting the references each time. Now the highlighted cell changes according to what you put in $G$3 and $H$3 without you having to do anything.

What this does is, for each cell, get its relative column/row references by calculating the difference from the row/column of the cell being checked (F9 being relativ,e it will change for each cell) and the row/column of the upper-left cell of the range ($F$9 will NOT change) - resulting in a range starting from 0, but since you use 0 in your table, that's fine. If not, you'll need to adjust by adding a constant. If both (the `AND` part) these indexes match, you apply the formatting. Note that if you use an `OR`, the whole row and whole column will be highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer.

Correct, I had already used the Conditional Formatting, but for this case it isn´t optimal.

Because I have no oppurtunities to change the thickness of the borders. I would like to have a red, thick border.

thanks for your help.
regards
thomas